# when i try mute someone with the normal role it gives me you cannot mute someone with an equal or higher role?

Tags: visual-studio, discord, discord.js

when i try mute someone with the normal role it gives me you cannot mute someone with an equal or higher role?

I'm also trying to get the bot to respond with "Given User is already muted" but when I mute someone who is already muted, it just responds saying I have muted the user.

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'mute',
  description: "This mutes a member",
  execute(message, args){


    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
      return message.channel.send("Sorry but you do not have permission to mute anyone" );
    }

    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
      return message.channel.send("I do not have permission to manage roles.");
    }

    const user = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (!user) {
      return message.channel.send("Please mention the member to who you want to mute");
    }
    
    if(user.id ===message.author.id){
      return message.channel.send("you can not mute yourself");
```

**This code**

```
    }
    // ... Other checks here
    
    // Compared after `user` is defined, and undefined check is done
    if (message.member.roles.highest.position) {
      return message.channel.send('You cannot mute someone with an equal or higher role');
    }
```

```
  let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")

  if(!reason) {
    return message.channel.send("Please Give the reason to mute the member")
    
  ;
 
  }



  //Mute ROLE
    let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === "Muted")
    let mainrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === "Verified")
   

    

    if(!muterole) {
    return message.channel.send("This server does not have role with name `Muted`")
  

    }
      
    
    

    user.roles.remove(mainrole)
    user.roles.add(muterole)
    



    message.channel.send(`You muted **${message.mentions.users.first().username}** Muted by:<@${message.author.id}>  For \`${reason}\``)
    
    user.send(`You are muted in **${message.guild.name}**,For \`${reason}\``)

    const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#1ABC9C')
  .setDescription(`${member} has now been muted`)
  .addField('Moderator', message.member, true)
  .addField('Member', member, true)
  .addField('Reason', reason)
  .setFooter(message.member.displayName,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
  .setTimestamp()
    const channel = message.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'logs' );channel.sendEmbed(newEmbed)
}

}
```

I also tried to make a embed sent into a specific channel,but since i cant mute a member i cant test it but if anything is wrong with please correct it thankyou

i get this error

**.addField('Member', member, true)**
^

**ReferenceError: member is not defined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not comparing the highest role position the author has against the highest role position the mentioned user has. You're just checking if the user has a highest role position.

```js
if (message.member.roles.highest.position <= user.roles.highest.position) {
  return message.channel.send('You cannot mute someone with an equal or higher role');
}
```

Comment: you forgot `cache`.

Comment: where about sorry

Comment: `const channel = message.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'logs' );channel.sendEmbed(newEmbed)`
Also what is `sendEmbed`

Comment: to send the embed 

Where do i put the `cache`

Comment: Please try to figure this out by yourself. I know StackOverflow surrounds helping developers, but it seems like you don't really know what you're doing and I feel like it would be better for us both if you were to look over the documents by yourself.

Comment: i know what im doing in some sense (with The basics)  but this is been annoying me for a 3 days now